# Using getJSON geonames lat and lng

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geonames

Im trying to get the lat and lng of a geonames JSON link but its returning no data, I think I have set it up correctly to work but nothing is being returned, can anyone see why?

```
 $.getJSON( "http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON?placename=BA215DY&country=uk&maxRows=1&radius=10&username=jolones", function( data ) {

    $("#lat").text(data.postalCodes[0].lat);
    $("#lng").text(data.postalCodes[0].lng);

  });
```

Comment: Well, at least for me, when I open that link in a browser, it says that the test limit is exceeded, so no data will be retrieved

Comment: @CalvinNunes yes sorry thats the test account try this http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON?placename=BA215DY&country=uk&maxRows=1&radius=10&username=jolones

Answer (score 0):

Call the Url in your Browser and this massage appears:
{"status":{"message":"the daily limit of 20000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.","value":18}}

Its exceeded. Thats why you get no data

EDIT:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON?placename=BA215DY&country=uk&maxRows=1&radius=10&username=jolones",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      method: 'GET',
      timeout: 3000,
      success: function(result) {
            console.log(result.postalCodes[0].lat)
      },
      error: function(){
          $('#error').show();
      }
    });
```

Works for me. PLS check your console if there are any CORS Policy problems.

Comment: yes sorry thats the test account try this http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON?placename=BA215DY&country=uk&maxRows=1&radius=10&username=jolones

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the cause or not . But i remember we got an issue it was not displaying data in live server.(it says in the network tab of the browser an error) So we changed this part of url:

```
http://api.geonames.org
```

to :

```
https://secure.geonames.org/
```

I hope it will help